# Can't use machine after log in

Tags: login

After I log in to my computer the only thing I can do is to move the mouse around. No keys gets any response at all. I can't even open the terminal using ctrl + alt + t. I have a bootable Ubuntu disk Image with me. Any idea how I can fix it?

The most likely reason of this error is that Ive been trying to install virtualbox on my computer. When trying to update my computer from the terminal there was something wrong with a virtualbox.list file, which i configured and then rebooted my computer. Then this happened....

Comment: It would help to know what operating system you're logging into when this problem happens. Is it correct that both mouse and keyboard works when booting up this Ubuntu disk?

Comment: Running Ubuntu 14.04, and yes everything works when I boot from the USB

Comment: Does everything visually look  as usual (ie. the launcher and panels) when you login? Can you mount the root partition of your Ubuntu installation from the USB and access the files in /var/log? If so /var/log/syslog might have something.

Comment: After login the the only thing that works properly is the mouse. Nothing else works. The log didn't give anything useful

Comment: Anything in the kern.log? Or in the files in /var/log/lightdm?

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure what to look for in the syslog or lightdm, some pointers would be helpful. Updated the original post with some additional information now.

Comment: I can access system setting now, any way that could fix my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same thing happened to me after installing virtual box. Somehow virtual box installation process sometimes uninstalls unity - the default launcher on ubuntu . To fix it, press Ctrl + Alt + F1 to enter the tty command shell and enter your username and password to login. Then type:

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Then type

```
sudo reboot
```

to restart your commander. Probably everything should work fine when you restart.

Comment: I'm trying to install unity but I'm getting a size mismatch error when I try to start the installation.

Comment: Everything works now